# Incorrect syntax near 'Full_Name'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlexception

I hope you can help, I'm trying to update my database file but I keep on getting an error and I'm not sure why, I don't have any problem adding data or displaying data it's just updating the data that I'm having problems with what could be the problem ?

the error is:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 'Full_Name'.
```

And this is my source code:

```
public void UpdateTable()
{
    try
    {
        string ID = Txt_IdNumber.Text;//ID Input
        string setYearFormat = Tdp_DateOfBirth.Value.ToString("yyyy");//Get only the year to calculate age
        string CurrentYear = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();//Get current year from system settings
        int getAge = Convert.ToInt32(CurrentYear) - Convert.ToInt32(setYearFormat);//Calculate Age
        string setDOB = Tdp_DateOfBirth.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");//Set TimeDatePicker to spesific Long date
        string Query = "UPDATE UserData" +
                       "SET Full_Name = @Fullname, Date_Of_Birth = @DateOfBirth, ID_Number = @IdNumber, Age = @Age" +
                       "WHERE Id = @Id";//Update query
        using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))//Connection to ConnectionString
        using (SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Query, Connection))//Sql Command to add/Update
        {
            Connection.Open();//Open Connection
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Dgv_Output.SelectedRows);//Add Values
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fullname", Txt_Fullname.Text);//Add Values
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", Convert.ToDateTime(setDOB));//Add Values
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdNumber", ID);//Add Values
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", getAge);//Add Values
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery();//Execute Non Query
        }

        Txt_Fullname.Clear();//Clear Textbox
        Txt_IdNumber.Clear();//Clear Textbox
        Tdp_DateOfBirth.Value = DateTime.Now;//Set TimeDatePicker to system date
        Txt_Fullname.Focus();//Focus on Full Name textbox
    }
    catch (Exception Err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Err.ToString(), "ERROR");
        using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter("UpdateError.txt"))//Write error to file
        {
            sr.Flush();//Flush existing data
            sr.WriteLine(Err);//Write new data
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you printed out the SQL, the problem would be obvious.  You are missing spaces where needed int he SQL statement.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a whitespace before the `set` and `where` clauses:

```
string Query = "UPDATE UserData " +
               // Was missing--^
               "SET Full_Name = @Fullname, Date_Of_Birth = @DateOfBirth, ID_Number = @IdNumber, Age = @Age " +
               // Here Too--------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
               "WHERE Id = @Id";//Update query
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to surround @Full_Name with single quotes:

'@Full_Name'